# Android deep linking not working from gmail

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Iam using deep linking from gmail to my application. after clicking deep link in gmail it opening in gmail webview and not supporting deeplink(Getting error like site can not be reache), if i open the same url in chrome then working fine.

Below is the code i added in manifest

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="XXXX"
                android:pathPrefix="/v1/user/reset_password/"
                android:scheme="http" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Please let me know how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Link is stripped by Gmail. And when I copy it and try to open it in browser it does not work (it tries to search instead), checked in Chrome and CM Browser

Answer (score 0):

Try these intent filters

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data android:scheme="file"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/html"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:scheme="about"/>
                <data android:scheme="javascript"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <!--
                  For these schemes where any of these particular MIME types
                  have been supplied, we are a good candidate.
            -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:scheme="inline"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/html"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- For viewing saved web archives. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:scheme="file"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-webarchive-xml"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="info.guardianproject.panic.action.TRIGGER"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I tired and still redirecting to gmail webview and getting "Site can not be reached error"